# EditText inside the IME itself (soft keyboard)

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, ime

I developed a soft keyboard for Android, and I want to enter text into **my own** `EditText` on the keyboard's main screen.

If I add an `EditText` to the keyboard Layout it is not receiving input from the keyboard (Neither if I put it in a `Dialog` or a `PopupWindow`). Also `requestFocus`, `setFocusable`, etc are not helping.

The only way an `EditText` receives the keyboard input is if I put it in a new `Activity` (which is not what I need). AI-Type Keyboard has done this. They allow Google Search from within the keyboard.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you solved it, then answer your own question.

Comment: Answer the question and "ACCEPT" the answer so the rest of us can learn from your experience.

Comment: You seem to have no idea what Stack Overflow is all about. If you solved then problem then provide the answer so others can learn from it. That you are asking nobody else to answer this question is just ridiculous. What in the world could be your reason for asking that?

Comment: My brother solved it.. I will ask him the solution and I will publish it as soon as it possible..

Comment: @AlonShmiel post your answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Immediately after editText VISABILITY change from GONE to VISIBLE, I had to set the focus and display the soft keyboard. I achieved this using the following code:

```
(new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
//      ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_find)).requestFocus();
//      
        EditText yourEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_find);
//      InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
//      imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

        yourEditText.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(
            SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN , 0, 0, 0));
        yourEditText.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(
            SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP , 0, 0, 0));                       

    }
}, 200);
```

It works for me with 100ms delay, but failed without any delay or with only a delay of 1ms.

Commented part of code shows another approach, which works only on some devices. I tested on OS versions 2.2 (emulator), 2.2.1 (real device) and 1.6 (emulator).

This approach saved me a lot of pain.

Comment: Didn't work in inside edittext which is above keyboardview . I have problem like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55176159/gboard-like-search-bar-in-android-ime) help us if u can.