# Gboard like search bar in Android IME

Tags: java, android, custom-keyboard, android-input-method, android-custom-keyboard

I want to create a search bar like Gboard inside keyboard (Android IME) as shown in picture.

Gboard Sample :

[image: Gboard Sample]

I have implemented an edittext on Keyboardview.xml as shown in picture.

My Implementation :

[image: My Implementation]

main_keyboard_frame.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="#cf060610"
    android:id="@+id/search_panel"
    android:visibility="invisible">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:hint="sdsddsd"
        android:id="@+id/ed"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

But the problem is when i press the edittext 2 (that is outside my ime) then my ime is open that contains edittext 1 as shown in above picture now when i write some thing from my ime it writes on edittext 2 instead of edittext 1 so i want to know whats the problem behind this? is it with focus? or something else?

Comment: abdul did y find any solution?

Comment: Please share if you find any solution?

Comment: yes, you can stop commit typed character when this search panel is open, and vice versa.

Comment: @AbdulWajid can you make snippet code of the solutions?

Answer (score 1):

So, I got a clue to solve this, from [Abdul Wajid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10517194/abdul-wajid)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55176159/gboard-like-search-bar-in-android-ime/69763255#comment105222477_55176159) above.

I use this [LatinIME](https://github.com/rkkr/simple-keyboard/blob/master/app/src/main/java/rkr/simplekeyboard/inputmethod/latin/LatinIME.java). Just need to update this line

```
public void onEvent(final Event event) {
        final InputTransaction completeInputTransaction =
                mInputLogic.onCodeInput(mSettings.getCurrent(), event);
        updateStateAfterInputTransaction(completeInputTransaction);
        mKeyboardSwitcher.onEvent(event, getCurrentAutoCapsState(), getCurrentRecapitalizeState());
}
```

stop commit the event key pressed with some logical case,

```
public void onEvent(final Event event) {
    if (mEditField.isFocused()){
        Log.d("LatinIME : field focused", "On Event: " + event.getTextToCommit() );
        mEditField.append(event.getTextToCommit());
    } else {
        final InputTransaction completeInputTransaction =
                mInputLogic.onCodeInput(mSettings.getCurrent(), event);
        updateStateAfterInputTransaction(completeInputTransaction);
        mKeyboardSwitcher.onEvent(event, getCurrentAutoCapsState(), getCurrentRecapitalizeState());
    }
}
```

and done, you can control the event type that pressed.