# Add EditText inside <Keyboard> in Android Studio

Tags: android, keyboard

there is some way to put an EditText inside `<Keyboard>` in Android Studio. I have reviewed different documentation but I have not found a solution.

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:keyWidth="10%p"
android:horizontalGap="0px"
android:verticalGap="0px"
android:keyHeight="60dp">
<Row android:rowEdgeFlags="top">
    <Key android:keyLabel="CONNECTION" android:keyWidth="100%p"  android:codes="1234"/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edtInput"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="textShortMessage|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:maxLength="2000"
        android:hint="@string/compose_hint"/>
</Row>
</Keyboard>
```

The only thing that is on my keyboard is

```
<Key android:keyLabel="CONNECTION" android:keyWidth="100%p"  android:codes="1234"/>
```

Comment: Um, how would that work? The user needs an input method editor to type into an `EditText`... so if the input method editor *itself* has the `EditText`, how would the user enter in anything?

Comment: The idea is to put an EditText on a keyboard to be able to handle sensitive information as a user and password, without the need to create another inferface.

Comment: @CommonsWare In google keyboard there is searchbox for gif and sticker

Comment: @Valdem007 I did put edittext above **keyboardview** but now I can't type in that edittext . So did u find any solution? I found same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55176159/6333971) here but no one answered him.

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: check my answer on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69763255/5327495