# How to create edit text inside keyboard view on android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard, gboard

Now I'm implementing the custom Android keyboard. And I would like to have a text field to search for contacts within the keyboard. But the edit text cannot edit.

Here is my code in the keyboard view

```
<LinearLayout
   android:gravity="center_vertical"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
           android:id="@+id/name"
           android:focusable="true"
           android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
           android:focusedByDefault="true"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

      <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="265dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Expected result**

[image]

**Thanks**

Comment: use a regular EditText

Comment: Not working, the edit text in an app has been focused, then I touch on my edit text on the keyboard and type something. But the edit text in the app still focus. And text not go inside my edit text at all.

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69763255/5327495